# Memory efficient dicts -- deriving an item's key from its value

Tags: python, dictionary, hashmap

I have a use case where I things that contain both a key and data.
I would like an efficient encoding of this data and the dict index of the data.
So Thing is a class, and dictionary is a dict index of its instances:

```
d = {}
class Thing: 
    def __init__(k,v): self.key=k; self.data=v; d[v]=self
```

Now I would like to pass Thing objects around in my code a single object as shown:

```
thing1, thing2 = d['thing1'], d['thing2']
```

This solution works.  I can index Things by key, and I can retrieve a key from each thing, but notice this solutions redundantly stores pointers to the key, both in the dict, and in the Thing object.

I could implement 'dict' from scratch in a way that I could tell it how to access the key from the value.  Many hash methods could thus avoid storing a second pointer to the key.

Do any of the Python dict implementations afford this flexibility?
If you are in a position to assert this is NOT possible, I would love to hear it. thx.

NOTICE:  The important point here is that later I wish to treat both key and data as a single object with a single pointer to it, and I do not want to heap allocate a tuple to achieve this, as that would defeat my original goal.

Comment: Why not `print "my key is %s and value is %s" % (k, obj)` ?? I you can access the value then you know the key and there is no need to derive it. If you want to get a key from a value, you actually want to build a second map in the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange to store the key in the value since you must have the key in order to get the value.

If you don't want to store it, you can get it with a special getter function:

```
def get_key_and_value(d, k):
    return (k, d[k])

obj = get_key_and_value(d, k)
print "my key is %s and value is %s" % (obj[0], obj[1])
```

Comment: this could work, but I expect many tiny objects here, so I don't want to create a second tuple object for each one of these objects.  also my code would need to pass the tuple around instead of the value... this would force me to dereference obj[1] everywhere in my code.  See my re-rewritten question.  I tried to be clearer of my goal.  thx

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained the use case well enough, so my guidance will not be very precise. I assume from your question you do NOT want to store the key in the value to conserve memory (as you demonstrated in your example -- and then rejected)?  And further, that you will have some operation that will require access to both the value and the key used to access that value.

Your belief that somehow the value retrieval function will have access to the raw key hash, and that from there it could somehow retrieve the key is incorrect. Python dict's do not surface this info.  I'm sure you could roll your own python extension to create this ability, but this sounds like alot of work (again -- without understanding the use case, I can't precisely determine whether the work is "worth it" or not).

Instead, why not just create your own `dict` class and add your code to the a custom method.  Something like this:

```
class MyDict(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = dict()
    def add(self, k, v):
        self.d[k] = v
    def later(self, k):
        print("my key is %s and value is %s" % (k, self.d[k]))
```

If this is not what you were hoping for -- can you describe the use case in more detail?

Comment: I tried to re-write my question.  your solution does not give me both key and value as a single object.  thx.